¿How to fix the responsive menu in boostrap?
in the inner page of this site the responsive menu is not working because I have to change the main menu in the inner pages (not in the home). When you turn on the inspector in your browser and activate the responsive mode, you can see the issue. So ¿How to fix the responsive menu in boostrap?
You can see it here
PD: In the home page the menu works fine.
Any help Will be grateful. THANKS
HTML Code:


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
* Desktop Navigation 
*/
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar>ul>li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 12px;
}

.navbar a,
.navbar a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: yellow;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 4px;
}

.navbar a i,
.navbar a:focus i {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar>ul>li>a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-primario);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover:before,
.navbar li:hover>a:before,
.navbar .active:before {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .active,
.navbar .active:focus,
.navbar li:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: calc(100% + 30px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul li {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #060c22;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul a:hover,
.navbar .dropdown ul .active:hover,
.navbar .dropdown ul li:hover>a {
  color: #5900ff;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 30px);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 1366px) {
  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
    left: -90%;
  }

  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown:hover>ul {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

/**
* Mobile Navigation 
*/
.mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-mobile .mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.navbar-mobile ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar-mobile>ul>li {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-mobile a:hover:before,
.navbar-mobile li:hover>a:before,
.navbar-mobile .active:before {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar-mobile a,
.navbar-mobile a:focus {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #060c22;
}

.navbar-mobile a:hover,
.navbar-mobile .active,
.navbar-mobile li:hover>a {
  color: var(--color-primario);
}

.navbar-mobile .getstarted,
.navbar-mobile .getstarted:focus {
  margin: 15px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul a:hover,
.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul .active:hover,
.navbar-mobile .dropdown ul li:hover>a {
  color: var(--color-primario);
}

.navbar-mobile .dropdown>.dropdown-active {
  display: block;
}
<a class="contacto scrollto" href="https://acrip.co/formulario-contacto-congreso/" target="_blank">Contacto</a>
<a class="brochure scrollto" href="https://acrip.co/formulario-congreso-brochure/" target="_blank">Descargar Brochure</a>
<a class="boletas scrollto" href="/#boletas">Comprar boletas</a>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar order-last order-lg-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="agenda-del-congreso.php">Agenda</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="conferencistas.php">Conferencistas</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="/#lugar">Lugar</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="/#patrocinadores">Patrocinadores</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Hospedaje</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="hotel-movich.php">Hotel Movich</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Venta de patrocinios</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="patrocinios-congreso.php">Patrocinios Congreso</a></li>
        <li><a href="planimetria-congreso.php">Planimetria Congreso</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
  <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i> </nav>
<!-- .navbar --> 



